# Wi-Fi hotspot from a device with no Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have some problems that result in my laptop being
unable to connect to my Ethernet network.
My desktop PC can connect to the Ethernet network.

Is there anyway to create a Wi-Fi hotspot from my desktop, which has no Wi-Fi capability, as my laptop can only connect to Wi-Fi connections?

Comment: Can you put a PCI WiFi card into your desktop or a USB dongle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if your PC has no wifi-card and you don't have a wifi-usb-stick or an access point at hand, there is no chance for you to get your laptop connected to wifi.

But, you can use your PC that is connected via ethernet to your router to change your settings so router enables a wifi, that your laptop can connect to - if your router has wifi-support.

Comment: Thanks my router is so far away from me I get wifi signal but its too weak and I just wanted to make it stronger by adding another access point thanks for answering